# CRM 2011: Unwanted text in Case's Description field after populating with email body

Tags: javascript, css, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am populating the Case(Incident) description with Email body using following javaScript. Its putting the following unwanted text in Description box.

`v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}`

**JavaScript**

```
o.EmailBody = oXml.selectSingleNode("template/body").text;
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue(o.EmailBody);
```

**Text Populated in Case Desc field**

`From: Joe.Blogs@anything.com
Sent: 04/04/2014 09:40:48
To: itsupport@example.com;
Subject: Test Subject`

`v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}`

`Hi,`

`Email Body Text.`

`Kind Regards`
Joe Bloggs

Can anyone please suggest me if there is any way to format this text? If not I would like to get rid of it completely.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
```

This is `Vector Markup Language`. Some email client and Word use it to format text. Try to determine in which part of body it is. After that you can select them(`document.getElementsByTagName("v:oval")` for example) crop it before pasting into attribute.

Can you provide us with `o.EmailBody` content?